# Supersized 3.2.7 doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, supersized

I have a jQuery plugin, supersized 3.2.7 working in Chrome and Firefox but just doesn't work in IE8. The pictures aren't loading.

The following is the error shown in the console.

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'thumb': object is null or undefined 
supersized.js?ver=3.4, line 13 character 1126
```

Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/supersized.js?ver=3.4"></script>
<script src="assets/js/supersized.shutter.js?ver=3.4"></script>
<script src="assets/js/easing.js"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(function($){

        jQuery.supersized({ 
            slide_interval: 5000,
            transition: 'fade',
            transition_speed: 1000,
            new_window: 0,
            horizontal_center: 1,
            progress_bar: 0,
            mouse_scrub: 0,                             
            slides:[

                {image: 'http://localhost/assets/images/city-at-night.jpg', title: '<h1>Discover More Possibilities...</h1><h2>At Lorem Ipsum, we fulfil your ideas'},
                {image: 'http://localhost/assets/images/modern-skyscraper.jpg', title: '<h1>Explore Our Capabilities</h1><h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'},
            ]

        });
    });

</script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try removing the last comma inside the slides array

```
slides:[

            {image: 'http://localhost/assets/images/city-at-night.jpg', title: '<h1>Discover More Possibilities...</h1><h2>At Lorem Ipsum, we fulfil your ideas'},
            {image: 'http://localhost/assets/images/modern-skyscraper.jpg', title: '<h1>Explore Our Capabilities</h1><h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'}
        ]
```

Comment: I had removed the last slide item but still not showing in the goddamn IE8.

Comment: remove the last comma not the last line

Comment: I have spent hours trying to fix this and all it was a little comma. thankyou :)

Comment: Little advice, if you have problem only with explorer, first find for lone commas in array declaration ! They crash the javascript engine, or better, the raise an error and stop the script execution!